# What are the available datasets for fake news detection

Tags: data-request

I want to know about recently available datasets for fake news analysis

Comment: There are methods/algorithms to automatically identify fake news, see e.g. [10.1002/pra2.2015.145052010082](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/pra2.2015.145052010082). I don't know whether there are ooen datasets.

Comment: So, you want samples of fake news so that you can analyze these news articles, right?

Comment: I need an annotated dataset with fake and real news articles with their links

Answer (score 5):

Buzzfeed News has been doing work on this, and has published data related to fake news, news patterns, and social media patterns on their Github: https://github.com/BuzzFeedNews/everything. Might be a good repo to browse.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some of the datasets available for fake news detection:

LIAR dataset: https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/william/data/liar_dataset.zip

BS Detector: https://github.com/bs-detector/bs-detector

Comment: one more: (CredBank) - http://compsocial.github.io/CREDBANK-data/

Comment: The LIAR dataset is at: https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~william/data/liar_dataset.zip

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the [Observatory on Social Media](http://osome.iuni.iu.edu/) (OSoMe) at Indiana University. The team have been been archiving 10% of public activity on Twitter for the last 10 years. The data isn't directly available to people not affiliated with the University they have a number of algorithms and visualization tools that you can run against the data.

- They have a service called '[BotSlayer](http://osome.iuni.iu.edu/tools/botslayer/)' which you can set up yourself on a free AWS instance and track certain hashtags and key phrases.
- There is also '[Botometer](https://botometer.iuni.iu.edu/)'which will assess any twitter user name and socre it based on how 'bot-like' it is.
- Finally, they have a tool called '[Hoaxy](https://hoaxy.iuni.iu.edu/)' which allows you to visualize the spread of a news or fake-news story across twitter to see which accounts are sharing/re-tweeting it.

Answer (score 0):

Kaggle hosts a dataset where the CSV has URL, title, text, and a flag "reliable" or "unreliable"

https://www.kaggle.com/c/fake-news/data

> id: unique id for a news article
>
> title: the title of a news article
>
> author: author of the news article text: the text of the article;
> could be incomplete
>
> label: a label that marks the article as potentially unreliable
>
> 1: unreliable
>
> 0: reliable

accessing the data requires registration