# Datasets for Fake news (Not Tweets and Facebook Posts)

Tags: data-request, releasing-data, news

Can you please tell me where can I find good pre-labeled datasets with real and fake news, but not tweets and facebook posts?

I found 4-5 on Kaggle, but I read that those are not real news (those are not real articles). I have also looked UCI ML Repository but those datasets are similar.

Basically I need dataset that has 3 columns, "title/headline", "text / paragraph text" and "label (true of fake)". 
Label does not need to be boolean, it can be more than 2 values, but dataset needs to be labeled.

Also, I do not want twitter and facebook posts, im interested in news articles.

Can you tell me other websites where I can find datasets like this?
Can you share some links where I can download such a thing?

Comment: Is the truth of newsmedia really a Boolean, and if so, who is defining it?

Comment: Funny @philshem ... there is truth in that!

Comment: @philshem I  agree, but now, I just need a datasets. There is no need to be just boolean (FAKE or TRUE), it can be more than 2 labels, but I need dataset that has headline, paragraph text and labels

Comment: duplicate?? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/10584/1511

Comment: Not duplicate, that answer was more than 3 years, its outdated

Answer (score 1):

From the Google Site.

Fact Check Tools API
Getting Started
The Google FactCheck ClaimReview Read/Write API
Typical use cases

Adding ClaimReview markup, editing ClaimReview Markup, deleting ClaimReview Markup for a site’s fact checking articles (URLs). To learn more about ClaimReview, visit the Fact Check developer docs.

https://developers.google.com/fact-check/tools/api/

Checking "Facts" are dependent upon the developers and/or readers perspective.  Each may be completely different.  I wish you luck but I wouldn't touch this with a 5000 foot pole.